If $R$ is a regular square-free ring, then $R$ is dual-square-free
Let $R$ be a ring with unity. We call $R$ regular if every principal (left) right ideal is a summand (i.e., generated by an idempotent). A module $M$ is called square-free if whenever $A,B$ are submodules of $M$ with $A \cong B$ and $A \cap B=0$, then $A=B=0$. The ring $R$ is called (left) right square-free if the module (${}_RR$) $R_R$ is square-free.
A module $M$ is called dual-square-free if there are no proper submodules $A,B$ of $M$ such that $M=A+B$ and $M/A \cong M/B$ as $R$-modules. The ring $R$ is called (left) right dual-square-free if the module (${}_RR$) $R_R$ is dual-square-free.
Recall that a ring $R$ is called abelian if the idempotents of $R$ are central. Recall that $R$ is called strongly regular if it is regular and abelian. Recall that strongly regular rings are precisely the regular square-free rings.
I want to prove that: $R$ is regular and right square-free $\Longrightarrow$ $R$ is right dual-square-free.
Proof Assume that $R$ is regular and right square-free. Let $A,B \subsetneqq R$ be two right ideals of $R$ such that $R=A+B$ and $R/A \cong R/B$ as right $R$-modules. Then
$\frac{I}{I \cap J} \cong \frac{I+J}{I}=\frac{R}{I} \cong \frac{R}{J} \cong \frac{I+J}{J} \cong \frac{I}{I \cap J}$ as right $R$-modules. If $I \cap J=0$, then we get $I \cong J$. Since $R$ is square-free, we have $I=J$ and thus $R=0$, a contradiction.
What can I do if $I \cap J \neq 0$?
I appreciate any help.
